# Angular 2 router ignoring my child <router-outlet> when creating multilevel child route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm having issues creating a component which contains a `<router-outlet>` to show children routes, which is at the same time a children of a parent with its own `<router-outlet>`.

Here's a plunk showing this behaviour with 4 different routes via `<a>` tags: https://plnkr.co/edit/0BNNkv?p=preview

The plunk has an app root component with empty routes as those are specified in the children and a parent component named `NavigatorComponent`, which is used to navigate. This 'parent' uses child routes as well as I was expecting to have the root routing module in the app component.

```
const navigatorRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
```

I'm trying to do this because I don't want any custom component to be the routing root.

For those proposing me to move the navigator to the parent I'll say that I already thought on this and I'll probably be finally doing it. However, I want to know if the pattern I'm suggesting is possible.

`AppComponent` loads a root routing module, which has no routes and the `NavigatorModule`.
`NavigatorModule` has four routes defined into it:

- First child route has a lazy-loading (with `loadChildren`) of a `Child1Component` which has no children into. When clicked no error is thrown in the console but nothing is loaded.
- Second child route has a eager-loading route to `Child2Component` which has at the same time two child routes declared into it. Those routes load with no issues but load in the `<router-outlet>` of the parent, instead of the one defined in `Child2Component`.
- Second child-children route has the same structure but it has the children routes defined in the parent `NavigatorComponent`, inside a `children` property. This behaves as desired but I was expecting to define nested routes to subchilds (p.e. `Subchild21Component`) inside `Child2Component`, instead of `NavigatorComponent`. I try to keep code uncoupled here. Please let me know if you find this to be exagerated.
- Third child route its similar to the first one (lazy-loading with `loadChildren`), but in this case it has children. Its behaviour its the same as the second child route.
- Fourth route it's the one that approaches the most to what I'm trying to achieve. It has several routes, declared in `Child4Component`, and are correctly loaded into its `<router-outlet>`.

The drawback with the last route is that the `Route` children have to be imported into a children property in the `NavigatorComponent`. This wouldn't be that bad (as routes are defined in the child anyway), but at the same time I have to define a `ModuleWithProviders` (`ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(EXP_ROUTES)`) into `Child4Component` using those routes and exporting out this module to `NavigatorComponent` to make this to work. This sounds like boilerplate code to me so I think I may be missing something. Moreover, I do not see how I can do lazy-loading here as I have to import the module into the navigator anyway.

I'm new to Angular (not just angular2, but angular in general) so I would thank any comment you have about the code, besides the question itself.

**Root routing**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const ROUTES: Routes = [

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const appRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

**Navigator module routes**

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'child1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'child1',             loadChildren: () => Child1Module  },
  { path: 'child2',             component: Child2Component },
  {
    path: 'child2-children',
    component: Child2Component,
    children: [
      { path: '',               redirectTo: 'subchild21'        },
      { path: 'subchild21',     component: Subchild21Component  },
      { path: 'subchild22',     component: Subchild22Component  }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'child3', loadChildren: () => Child3Module },
  { path: 'child4', component: Child4Component, children: [...EXP_ROUTES ] }
];

const navigatorRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES);
```

**Navigator component/template**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navigator',
    template:
    `<h5>We navigate here!</h5>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <a routerLink="child1" title="Lazy-loading. No children">Child1</a>
        <a routerLink="child2" title="Eager-loading. Children defined in child component">Child2</a>
        <a routerLink="child2-children" title="Eager-loading. Children defined in the parent">Child2-Children</a>
        <a routerLink="child3" title="Lazy-loading. Children defined in the children">Child3</a>
        <a routerLink="child4" title="Eager-loading. Children defined in the parent and the children">Child4</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class NavigatorComponent { }
```

**Child1 routes**

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Child1Component  }
];

const child1RoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES);
```

**Child2 component/module**

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
      { path: 'child2',
        children: [
          { path: 'subchild21', component: Subchild21Component  },
          { path: 'subchild22', component: Subchild22Component  }
        ]
      }
];

const child2RoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES);

@Component({
  selector: 'child2',
    template:
    `<h5>This is child 2!</h5>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <a routerLink="subchild21">Subchild21</a>
        <a routerLink="subchild22">Subchild22</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class Child2Component { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ child2RoutingModule, Subchild21Module, Subchild22Module ],
  exports:      [ Child2Component ],
  declarations: [ Child2Component ]
})
export class Child2Module { }
```

**Child3 component/module**

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Child3Component,
    children: [
      { path: '',               redirectTo: 'subchild31'        },
      { path: 'subchild31',     component: Subchild21Component  },
      { path: 'subchild32',     component: Subchild22Component  }
    ]
  }
];

const child3RoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES);

@Component({
  selector: 'child3',
  template:
    `<h5>This is child 3!</h5>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <a routerLink="subchild31">Subchild31</a>
        <a routerLink="subchild32">Subchild32</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class Child3Component { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ child3RoutingModule, ],
  exports:      [ Child3Component, ],
  declarations: [ Child3Component ]
})
export class Child3Module { }
```

**Child4 component/module**

```
export const EXP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'subchild41' },  
    { path: 'subchild41', component: Subchild21Component    },
    { path: 'subchild42', component: Subchild22Component    }
];

const child4RoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(EXP_ROUTES);

@Component({
  selector: 'child4',
    template:
    `<h5>This is child 4!</h5>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <a routerLink="subchild41">Subchild41</a>
        <a routerLink="subchild42">Subchild42</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class Child4Component { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ child4RoutingModule, Subchild21Module, Subchild22Module ],
  exports:      [ Child4Component ],
  declarations: [ Child4Component ]
})
export class Child4Module { }
```

Comment: I agree with your assessment that NavigatorModule should be depreciated and it's functionality be moved to the AppModule. Unless you have another completely separate set of functionality that you're going to implement outside of NavigatorModule, you're overcomplicating things by adding that extra layer.
Secondly, you can achieve the same effect from `loadChildren: () => ModuleName` by doing `loadChildren: ModuleName`.